# how to create Spotify developer account in india

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, spotify

Hi I am working on one iOS Entertainment project and implementing spotify SDK but I am facing one issue that I can't Register in Spotify Developer account.

When I am  trying to access with my Facebook credentials it says "**invalid credentials**" and  I'm using   normal signup  Spotify account it says "**Spotify is not available in your country**"

[image]

Any one please guide me how to solve this issue?

Comment: Use proxy. http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110603153704AAbIcsp

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about creating an account on for a web service.

Answer (score 2):

Kirti , well I think I can offer you a workaround. What you can do is open a proxy site from any of the various proxy servers which are mainly based in the US or any other country approved by spotify. You can get the list of approved countries [here](https://www.spotify.com/us/select-your-country/). Now from this proxy site go to spotify. Make your account ! Hope this helps.

Comment: if we are creating app using proxy site and then after upload app into app store then it will working this app in India or what?